# Prolog adding visited squares to a list and then displaying that list

Tags: prolog

I have made a game in Prolog application were an archer will move into an adjacent square that is safe on a grid that is in a 4 x 4 system. The user can input co-ordinates that they want to go to, e.g. if I type in `safe_square(4,1,3,1)`. the archer will move from **4,1 to 3,1**. What I want to do is display any squares that the archer has visited by adding them to a list and then displaying that list.

My code is as follows to create the board, print the board, populate the board, and move through the board.

```
% This buffer is for notes you don't want to save.
% If you want to create a file, visit that file with C-x C-f,
% then enter the text in that file's own buffer.

% square(row,col,val)
:- dynamic square/3.
:- dynamic show/1.

createBoard(N) :- 
               retractall(show(_)),
           assert(show([[1,1]])),
           retractall(square(_,_,_)),
           createBoard(N,N).

testBoard :-
    retractall(square(_,_,_)),
    retractall(show(_)),
    assert(show([[4,1]])),
        assert(show([[3,1]])),
        assert(show([[2,1]])),

    asserta(square(1,1,[e])),
    asserta(square(1,2,[e])),
    asserta(square(1,3,[s])),
    asserta(square(1,4,[e])),
    asserta(square(2,1,[e])),
    asserta(square(2,2,[b,s])),
    asserta(square(2,3,[w])),
    asserta(square(2,4,[g,s])),
    asserta(square(3,1,[b])),
    asserta(square(3,2,[p])),
    asserta(square(3,3,[g,b,s])),
    asserta(square(3,4,[x])),
    asserta(square(4,1,[a,e])),
    asserta(square(4,2,[b])),
    asserta(square(4,3,[e])),
    asserta(square(4,4,[g])).



createBoard(0,_).
createBoard(Row,Col) :-
 createCol(Row,Col),
 NextRow is Row -1,
 createBoard(NextRow,Col).

createCol(Row,1) :-
      assertz(square(Row,1,[e])).
createCol(CurrentRow,CurrentCol) :-
        assertz(
    square(CurrentRow,CurrentCol,[e])
            ),
        NextCol is CurrentCol -1,
        createCol(CurrentRow,NextCol).

maxBound(B) :-   %
    setof(Row,square(Row,_,_),L), % L = [1,2,3,4]
    reverse(L,[B|_]). % L = [4,3,2,1] => B = 4


printBoard :-
    maxBound(Bound),
    setof([R,C,Contents],
        square(R,C,Contents),Squares),
           % Squares = [[1,1,[e]],[1,2,[e],....]
    printSquares(Squares,Bound),nl.

printSquares([],_). % stop if we printed all the squares

printSquares(S,0) :-  % Print New Row
    maxBound(B),
    nl,printSquares(S,B).

% Print a square that is revealed
% Squares = [[1,1,[e]] |   [1,2,[e],....]
printSquares([[R,C,Contents]|Rest],ColCount) :-
    show(L),
    member([R,C],L),
    extract([p,w],Contents,Display),
    padd(Display,3,Padded),
    write(Padded),
    NewColCount is ColCount - 1,
    printSquares(Rest,NewColCount).

% Print one that is not visible
printSquares([_|Rest],ColCount) :-
    write('[----]'),
    NewColCount is ColCount - 1,
    printSquares(Rest,NewColCount).

extract([],L,L).
extract([H|T],L,FinalList) :-
    delete(L,H,ReducedL),
    % delete fails if H is not in the contents
    extract(T,ReducedL,FinalList).
extract([_|T],L,FinalList) :-
    extract(T,L,FinalList).

padd(L,Max,P) :-
    length(L,Len),
    paddout(L,Max,Len,P).

paddout(L,Max,Max,L).
paddout(L,Max,Len,[' '|P]) :-
    Len1 is Len + 1,
    paddout(L,Max,Len1,P).



% you can place a piece on a board of N size if you can generate a row and column value and you can place that piece on an square empty square
place(Piece,N) :-
 Row1 is random(N),
 Col1 is random(N),
 place(Piece,Row1,Col1,N).

% you can place a pit if the square is empty at the specified
% position
place(p,Row,Col,_) :-
 square(Row,Col,[e]),
 retract(square(Row,Col,[e])),
 assert(square(Row,Col,[p])).

% Find an Item at a position R,C by
% examining the contents of the R,C, location
find(R,C,Item) :-
    square(R,C,Contents),
    member(Item,Contents).


safe_square(Xa,Ya,X,Y) :-
    maxBound(N),
    adjacent(Xa,Ya,X,Y,N),
    safe(X,Y),
    move(Xa,Ya,X,Y),
    retract(show(L)),
    append([[X,Y]],L,NewL),
    assert(show(NewL)).


safe_square(Xa,Ya,X,Y) :-
    maxBound(N),
    adjacent(Xa,Ya,X,Y,N),
    glitter(X,Y),
    move(Xa,Ya,X,Y),
    retract(show(L)),
    append([[X,Y]],L,NewL),
    assert(show(NewL)).

safe_square(Xa,Ya,X,Y) :-
    maxBound(N),
    adjacent(Xa,Ya,X,Y,N),
    glitter(X,Y),
    move(Xa,Ya,X,Y),
    retract(show(L)),
    append([[X,Y]],L,NewL),
    assert(show(NewL)).

safe_square(Xa,Ya,X,Y) :-
    maxBound(N),
    adjacent(Xa,Ya,X,Y,N),
    empty(X,Y),
    move(Xa,Ya,X,Y),
    retract(show(L)),
    append([[X,Y]],L,NewL),
    assert(show(NewL)).

safe_square(Xa,Ya,X,Y) :-
    maxBound(N),
    adjacent(Xa,Ya,X,Y,N),
    gold(X,Y),
    move(Xa,Ya,X,Y),
    retract(show(L)),
    append([[X,Y]],L,NewL),
    assert(show(NewL)).





move(Xa,Ya,X,Y) :-
    retract(square(Xa,Ya,ListFrom)),
    delete(ListFrom,a,Existing),
    retract(square(X,Y,ListTo)),
    append([a],ListTo,NextPositionList),
    assert(square(Xa,Ya,Existing)),
    assert(square(X,Y,NextPositionList)),
    !.

safe(X,Y) :-
    square(X,Y,L),
    \+ member(p,L),
    \+ member(w,L).

gold(X,Y) :-
    square(X,Y,L),
    member(x,L).
glitter(X,Y):-
    square(X,Y,L),
    member(g,L).
empty(X,Y):-
    square(X,Y,L),
    member(e,L).


adjacent(R,C,Ar,Ac,_) :- Ar is R -1,  Ar >= 1,  Ac is C.
adjacent(R,C,Ar,Ac,N) :-  Ar is R + 1,  Ar =< N,  Ac is C.
adjacent(R,C,Ar,Ac,_) :-  Ac is C - 1,  Ac >= 1,  Ar is R.
adjacent(R,C,Ar,Ac,N) :-  Ac is C + 1,  Ac =< N, Ar is R.


run:-
    printBoard,
    at(Xa,Ya,X,Y),
    move(Xa,Ya,X,Y),
    get0(_),
    run.
```

Comment: I don't see a question. And you'll need to explain what you mean by *highlight*.

Comment: The question is how would I highlight the square the archer has visited. I just want to highlight the square on the grid yellow if the archer has visited them. @lurker

Comment: I'm not sure what Prolog framework you're using that does graphical representation of data. Are you asking how to literally highlight a square, or are you really asking how to identify the square to be highlighted?

Comment: WHat I am trying to do is highlight the route that the archer takes. Is that possible @lurker

Comment: You haven't provided enough information. What Prolog framework (system) are you using?

Comment: SWI-Prolog (AMD64, Multi-threaded, version 7.2.3) is what I'm using

Comment: I don't see any graphical interface code in your source so far. So you're going to have to start here: [Graphics applications](http://www.swi-prolog.org/Graphics.html).

Comment: @lurker He means he wants to display the route that the robot took, so if the went from position 4,1 to 3,4 to get to the end display that path.

Comment: @GuinnessIsLife I understand that. He indicated "highlighting" squares "on a grid". Therefore, I assume he's looking for a graphical interface. The link I provided is the place to start since there are no graphical interface elements in the program so far.

Comment: @lurker, yes he did but he actually didn't ask the question write what he ideally would want is to add all the co-ordinates 4,1 to 3,4 to a list and display that list.

Comment: @GuinnessIsLife see my question in the 3rd comment, *Are you asking how to literally highlight a square, or are you really asking how to identify the square to be highlighted?* And the answer came back in the next comment, *What I am trying to do is highlight the route that the archer takes.*. If that's not a question specifically about the graphics, then it needs clarification.

Comment: I edited my question @lurker

Comment: The typical way of doing something like this is to include two arguments to your predicate. One is the current state, and the second is the new state. In this case, the *state* is the list of visited squares. The initial value of the current state would be the empty list (`[]`). I didn't study your code in detail, these would probably be added to your `move/4` predicate, making it a 6-argument predicate. Your initial call to `move` would have `[]` as the current state. When the call to `move` finishes, the new state argument should be the whole list, which you can display as you wish.

Comment: can you write a list like this write(ListFrom)?

Comment: Yes you can. It will just display it as expected, a Prolog list.  If you want something different, you could write your own `write_list(List)` predicate to format it to your taste.